Script to automate lipsynching
I've been using the Merlin plugin to write Python scripts and think I'm close to a way to use CSV viseme data to automate lip synching.
The approach seems promising - have the script open a csv file (or just include the data in the script), then associate a pose with each viseme at the frame indicated in the csv or data.
I suspect my problem is that my project is disorganized - and that the script is not looking at either the right object (like I'm pointing at the wrong place in the hierarchy) or that the pose names don't provide enough of the path to find and apply the pose data.
[edit: in this version I tried pointing at the 'actions' but again, don't think it's able to resolve the paths correctly]
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
The Python script follows or is in a text file here and here is a link to my blender file :
import bpy

# Define frame numbers and corresponding viseme labels
viseme_data = [
    (0, 'Neutral'),
    (53, 'Oh'),
    (56, 'Neutral'),
    (59, 'M'),
    (60, 'Ee'),
    (66, 'R'),
    (67, 'M'),
    (70, 'Neutral'),
    (73, 'M'),
    (74, 'Ee'),
    (76, 'F'),
    (78, 'Uh'),
    (80, 'M'),
    (82, 'Ah'),
    (86, 'D'),
    (88, 'L'),
    (90, 'Oh'),
    (91, 'M'),
    (92, 'L'),
    (99, 'Ee'),
    (101, ''),
    (103, 'M'),
    (105, 'Uh'),
    (108, 'S'),
    (109, 'M'),
    (113, 'Uh'),
    (115, 'D'),
    (118, 'Ee'),
    (120, 'S'),
    (121, 'Woo'),
    (124, 'R'),
    (127, 'Neutral')
]

# Path to the current file/actions/ folder
actions_path = bpy.path.abspath('//actions/')  # Current file/actions path

# Pose name mapping
pose_name_mapping = {
    'Neutral': 'Martin_neutral',
    'Oh': 'martin_Oh',
    'M': 'martin_B_M',
    'Ee': 'martin_Ee',
    'R': 'martin_R001',
    'S': 'martin_S',
    'D': 'martin_D',
    'L': 'martin_L',
    'Uh': 'martin_Uh',
    'F': 'martin_F',
    'Ah': 'martin_Ah',
    'Woo': 'martin_Woo'
    # Add more mappings as needed
}

# Set poses based on viseme labels for each frame
for frame_number, viseme_label in viseme_data:
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_number)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
    
    character_object = bpy.data.objects.get('martin_20230702_rig')  # Replace 'martin20230702_rig' with the correct object name
    if character_object:
        pose_name = pose_name_mapping.get(viseme_label)
        if pose_name:
            action_name = f"{actions_path}{pose_name}"  # Construct action name based on pose name
            action = bpy.data.actions.get(action_name)
            if action:
                character_object.animation_data_create()
                character_object.animation_data.action = action  # Apply the action to the character
            else:
                print("Action not found for pose name:", pose_name)
        else:
            print("Pose name not found for viseme label:", viseme_label)
    else:
        print("Character object not found in the scene.")

